# find out null values of a row django

Tags: python, django

I have bellow details :

```
Models.py:
    class   ip(models.Model):
      IP=models.CharField(max_length=20)
      created_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
      url=models.URLField(null=True)
      agent=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
      country=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
      isp=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

      def __unicode__(self):
            return self.IP
```

I have some null values in country field,  but no null value to
 IP, Now I want to find out only those IPs which is having country as null
 value. From the bellow given lines I can see the unique IPs

```
v=[]
for o in ip.objects.values_list('IP'):
   if o in v:
       pass
   else:
       v.append(o)
```

Now I want to only those ips which is having null value on country field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter on that field:

```
ip.objects.filter(country=None).values_list('IP').distinct()
```

Note, the distinct() at the end removes the need for the for loop.